# Socket Programming — recv() cannot get all data

Tags: c, sockets, recv

I am learning socket programming in C language, and this is an incomprehensible problem I encountered during my study.

Today I am trying to send a HTTP request to my test server which host an Apache example website, then receive the response from test server. Here is a part of my receive code.

```
unsigned long recv_size = 0;
unsigned long response_size = 4096;
int ret = 0;
char *recv_buff = (char *)malloc(response_size);

while (1)
{
    // ret = recv(socket, recv_buff, response_size, MSG_WAITALL); // cannot get all data
    ret = read(socket, recv_buff, response_size); // same effect as the above
    recv_size += ret;
    if (ret < 0)
        error(strerror(errno));
    else if (ret == 0)
        break; // all data recved
}
```

The normal result of my test with burpsuit is this.

[image: burpsuit result]

But what I received with the C language program was incomplete data.

[image: C program result]

I searched the reason for one night, but I still did not find a solution for my problem. Whether it is to set the buff to a super large size or any other method, the complete data cannot be accepted at all.

[image: wireshark]

The traffic monitored from wireshark is ok, but my program still cannot receive the complete data. What is the problem?

If you know why, please let me know. THX. (o゜▽゜)o☆

**UPDATE**

The `while` loop will execute twice, and first time the value of `ret` is `3343`, and second time is `0`, so the loop will stop here.

[image: gdb]

Comment: Is there something you're doing with `recv_buff` in your real code that you didn't include here? Because as it is every call to `read()` is overwriting the first `ret` bytes...

Comment: 'if (ret == 0)' is not the correct condition for HTTP 1.1

Comment: ....though with Content-Length of 3041, I would expect that all the data would fit in your buffer in one read, (though, 'cos TCP streaming, that's not remotely guaranteed).  Why have you not printffed out 'ret' as a debug measure?

Comment: `read` doesn't have to return all the data at once. It's allowed to return a random amount of data, and you have to prepare for it.

Comment: @Shawn Since the memory is applied for recv_buff, recv_buff has not had any operation until the recv() function is called.（￣﹏￣）

Comment: @MartinJames Sorry, I didn't know that before, I had read the recv() manual and the manual wrote these words `When a stream socket peer has performed an orderly shutdown, the return value will be 0 (the traditional "end-of-file" return)`, so I use this condition to break the while loop.

Comment: @user253751 ... and how do I receive the complete data? (￣３￣)

Comment: @MartinJames This loop will execute twice, first time the `ret` value is `3343`, and second time value is `0`, so program quit the loop. I will post a picture about the `gdb`   debug result on my question. （＞﹏＜）

Comment: @Hatsune you keep calling it until you've got the amount of data you want. How much data do you want?

Answer (score 1):

You *can* get a short read on a socket.

But, your code to handle that has a few issues.

You're allocating a buffer of size `response_size`. You are *always* reading that amount instead of reducing the amount read by the amount you've already read on a prior loop iteration.

This can cause you to read past the end of the buffer causing UB (undefined behavior).

Your termination condition is `if (ret == 0)`. This can fail if another packet arrives "early". You'll never see a `ret` of 0, because the partial data from the *next* packet will make it non-zero

Here's the corrected code:

```
#if 0
unsigned long recv_size = 0;
#endif

unsigned long response_size = 4096;
int ret = 0;
char *recv_buff = (char *) malloc(response_size);

#if 1
unsigned long remaining_size = response_size;
unsigned long offset = 0;
#endif

for (;  remaining_size > 0;  remaining_size -= ret, offset += ret) {
    ret = read(socket, &recv_buff[offset], remaining_size);
    if (ret < 0)
        error(strerror(errno));
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

The above code corrects some of the issues. But, for a variable length source [such as `http`], we don't know how much to read at the outset.

So, we have to parse the headers and look for the "Content-Length" field. This will tell us how much to read.

So, we'd like to have line oriented input for the headers. Or, manage our own buffer

Assuming we can parse that value, we have to wait for the empty line to denote the start of the payload. And, then we can loop on that exact amount.

Here's some code that attempts the header parsing and saving of the payload. I've coded it, but not compiled it. So, you can take it as pseudo code:

```
unsigned long recv_size = 0;
unsigned long response_size = 4096;
char *recv_buff = malloc(response_size + 1);

// line oriented header buffer
char *endl = NULL;
unsigned long linelen;
char linebuf[1000];

int ret = 0;

// read headers
while (1) {
    // fill up a chunk of data
    while (recv_size < response_size) {
        recv_buff[recv_size] = 0;

        // do we have a line end?
        endl = strstr(recv_buff,"\r\n");
        if (endl != NULL)
            break;

        ret = read(socket, &recv_buff[recv_size], response_size - recv_size);
        if (ret < 0)
            error(strerror(errno));
        if (ret == 0)
            break;

        recv_size += ret;
    }

    // error -- no line end but short read
    if (endl == NULL)
        error(strerror(errno));

    // copy header to work buffer
    linelen = endl - recv_buff;
    memcpy(linebuf,recv_buff,linelen);
    linebuf[linelen] = 0;

    // remove header from receive buffer
    linelen += 2;
    recv_size -= linelen;
    if (recv_size > 0)
        memcpy(recv_buff,&recv_buff[linelen],recv_size);

    // stop on end of headers (back to back "\r\n")
    if ((recv_size >= 2) && (recv_buff[0] == '\r') && (recv_buff[1] == '\n')) {
        memcpy(recv_buff,&recv_buff[2],recv_size - 2);
        recv_size -= 2;
        break;
    }

    // parse line work buffer for keywords ... (e.g.)
    content_length = ...;
}

// save payload to file
while (content_length > 0) {
    // write out prior payload amount
    if (recv_size > 0) {
        write(file_fd,recv_buff,recv_size);
        content_length -= recv_size;
        recv_size = 0;
        continue;
    }

    recv_size = read(socket,recv_buff,response_size);
    if (recv_size < 0)
        error(strerror(errno));
    if (recv_size == 0)
        break;
}
```

---

**UPDATE #2:**

> Yeah, it hard to make the pseudo code run, and the returned values are all garbled

Okay, here is a soup-to-nuts working version that I've tested against my own `http` server.

I had to create my own routines for the parts you *didn't* post (e.g. `connect`, etc.).

At the core, there might have been a minor tweak to the buffer slide code [it was sliding by an extra 2 bytes in one place], but, otherwise it was pretty close to my previous version

```
// htprcv/htprcv.c -- HTTP receiver

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <error.h>

#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

typedef unsigned char byte;

#define HTPSLIDE(_rmlen) \
    recv_size = htpslide(recv_buff,recv_size,_rmlen)

#define _dbgprt(_fmt...) \
    fprintf(stderr,_fmt)

#if DEBUG || _USE_ZPRT_
#define dbgprt(_lvl,_fmt...) \
    do { \
        if (dbgok(_lvl)) \
            _dbgprt(_fmt); \
    } while (0)
#define dbgexec(_lvl,_expr) \
    do { \
        if (dbgok(_lvl)) \
            _expr; \
    } while (0)
#else
#define dbgprt(_lvl,_fmt...) \
    do { \
    } while (0)
#define dbgexec(_lvl,_expr) \
    do { \
    } while (0)
#endif

#define dbgok(_lvl) \
    opt_d[(byte) #_lvl[0]]
byte opt_d[256];

char *opt_o;

#define HEXMAX      16

// htpconn -- do connect to server
int
htpconn(const char *hostname,unsigned short portno)
{
    struct addrinfo hints, *res;
    struct hostent *hostent;
    int ret;
    char portstr[20];
    int sockfd;

    /* Prepare hint (socket address input). */
    hostent = gethostbyname(hostname);
    if (hostent == NULL)
        error(1,errno,"htpconn: gethostbyname -- %s\n",hostname);

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;          // ipv4
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;    // tcp
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;        // fill in my IP for me

    sprintf(portstr, "%d", portno);
    getaddrinfo(NULL, portstr, &hints, &res);

    sockfd = socket(res->ai_family, res->ai_socktype, res->ai_protocol);
    if (sockfd < 0)
        error(1,errno,"htpconn: socket\n");

    // do the actual connection
    ret = connect(sockfd, res->ai_addr, res->ai_addrlen);
    if (ret < 0)
        error(1,errno,"htprcv: read header\n");

    return sockfd;
}

// htpslide -- slide buffer (strip out processed data)
size_t
htpslide(char *recv_buff,size_t recv_size,int slidelen)
{
    size_t new_size;

    if (slidelen > recv_size)
        slidelen = recv_size;

    new_size = recv_size - slidelen;

    dbgprt(S,"htpslide: slidelen=%d recv_size=%zu new_size=%zu\n",
        slidelen,recv_size,new_size);

    memcpy(&recv_buff[0],&recv_buff[slidelen],new_size);

    return new_size;
}

// _htphex -- dump a line in hex
void
_htphex(unsigned long off,const void *vp,size_t xlen)
{
    const byte *bp = vp;
    int idx;
    int chr;
    char hexbuf[200];
    char alfbuf[200];

    char *hexptr = hexbuf;
    char *alfptr = alfbuf;

    for (idx = 0;  idx < HEXMAX;  ++idx) {
        chr = bp[idx];

        if ((idx % 4) == 0)
            *hexptr++ = ' ';

        if (idx < xlen) {
            hexptr += sprintf(hexptr,"%2.2X",chr);
            if ((chr < 0x20) || (chr > 0x7E))
                chr = '.';
        }
        else {
            hexptr += sprintf(hexptr,"  ");
            chr = ' ';
        }

        *alfptr++ = chr;
    }

    *hexptr = 0;
    *alfptr = 0;

    _dbgprt("  %8.8lX: %s  *%s*\n",off,hexbuf,alfbuf);
}

// htphex -- dump a buffer in hex
void
htphex(const char *buf,size_t buflen,const char *reason)
{
    size_t off = 0;
    size_t xlen;

    if (reason != NULL)
        _dbgprt("htphex: DUMP buf=%p buflen=%zu (from %s)\n",
            buf,buflen,reason);

    for (;  buflen > 0;  buflen -= xlen, buf += xlen, off += xlen) {
        xlen = buflen;
        if (xlen > HEXMAX)
            xlen = HEXMAX;
        _htphex(off,buf,xlen);
    }
}

// htpsym -- get symbol/value
int
htpsym(char *linebuf,char *sym,char *val)
{
    char *cp;
    int match;

    dbgprt(H,"htpsym: PARAM linebuf='%s'\n",linebuf);

    // FORMAT:
    //   foo-bar: baz
    do {
        match = 0;

        cp = strchr(linebuf,':');
        if (cp == NULL)
            break;

        *cp++ = 0;
        strcpy(sym,linebuf);

        for (;  (*cp == ' ') || (*cp == '\t');  ++cp);
        strcpy(val,cp);

        match = 1;

        dbgprt(H,"htpsym: SYMBOL sym='%s' val='%s'\n",sym,val);
    } while (0);

    return match;
}

// htprcv -- receive server response
void
htprcv(int sockfd,int fdout)
{
    size_t recv_size = 0;
    size_t response_size = 4096;
    char *recv_buff = malloc(response_size + 1);

    // line oriented header buffer
    char *endl = NULL;
    size_t linelen;
    char linebuf[1000];

    ssize_t ret = 0;
    off_t content_length = 0;

    // read headers
    while (1) {
        // fill up a chunk of data
        while (recv_size < response_size) {
            recv_buff[recv_size] = 0;

            // do we have a line end?
            endl = strstr(recv_buff,"\r\n");
            if (endl != NULL)
                break;

            // read a chunk of data
            ret = read(sockfd,&recv_buff[recv_size],response_size - recv_size);
            if (ret < 0)
                error(1,errno,"htprcv: read header\n");
            if (ret == 0)
                break;

            recv_size += ret;
            dbgprt(R,"htprcv: READ ret=%zd\n",ret);
            dbgexec(R,htphex(recv_buff,recv_size,"htprcv/READ"));
        }

        // error -- no line end but short read
        if (endl == NULL)
            error(1,0,"htprcv: no endl\n");

        // copy header to work buffer
        linelen = endl - recv_buff;
        memcpy(linebuf,recv_buff,linelen);
        linebuf[linelen] = 0;

        // remove header from receive buffer
        linelen += 2;
        HTPSLIDE(linelen);

        // stop on end of headers (back to back "\r\n")
        if ((recv_size >= 2) &&
            (recv_buff[0] == '\r') && (recv_buff[1] == '\n')) {
            HTPSLIDE(2);
            break;
        }

        // parse line work buffer for keywords ...
        char sym[100];
        char val[1000];
        if (! htpsym(linebuf,sym,val))
            continue;

        if (strcasecmp(sym,"Content-Length") == 0) {
            content_length = atoi(val);
            continue;
        }
    }

    // save payload to file
    while (content_length > 0) {
        // write out prior payload amount
        if (recv_size > 0) {
            dbgexec(W,htphex(recv_buff,recv_size,"htprcv/WRITE"));

            ret = write(fdout,recv_buff,recv_size);
            if (ret < 0)
                error(1,errno,"htprcv: write body\n");

            content_length -= recv_size;
            recv_size = 0;
            continue;
        }

        // read in new chunk of payload
        ret = read(sockfd,recv_buff,response_size);
        if (ret < 0)
            error(1,errno,"htprcv: read body\n");
        if (ret == 0)
            break;

        recv_size = ret;
    }

    free(recv_buff);
}

// htpget -- do initial dialog
void
htpget(int sockfd,const char *hostname,const char *file)
{
    char *bp;
    char buf[1024];
    ssize_t resid;
    ssize_t xlen;
    size_t off;

    bp = buf;

    if (file == NULL)
        file = "/";
    bp += sprintf(bp,"GET %s HTTP/1.1\r\n",file);

    if (hostname == NULL)
        hostname = "localhost";
    bp += sprintf(bp,"Host: %s\r\n",hostname);

    if (0) {
        bp += sprintf(bp,"User-Agent: %s\r\n","curl/7.61.1");
    }
    else {
        bp += sprintf(bp,"User-Agent: %s\r\n","htprcv");
    }
    bp += sprintf(bp,"Accept: */*\r\n");

    bp += sprintf(bp,"\r\n");

    resid = bp - buf;
    off = 0;
    for (;  resid > 0;  resid -= xlen, off += xlen) {
        xlen = write(sockfd,buf,resid);
        if (xlen < 0)
            error(1,errno,"htpget: write error\n");
    }
}

// main -- main program
int
main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    char *cp;
    char *portstr;
    unsigned short portno;
    int sockfd;
    int filefd;
    char url[1000];

    --argc;
    ++argv;

    //setlinebuf(stdout);
    setlinebuf(stderr);

    for (;  argc > 0;  --argc, ++argv) {
        cp = *argv;
        if (*cp != '-')
            break;

        cp += 2;
        switch(cp[-1]) {
        case 'd':  // debug options
            if (*cp == 0)
                cp = "SHRW";
            for (;  *cp != 0;  ++cp)
                opt_d[(byte) *cp] = 1;
            break;

        case 'o':  // output file
            opt_o = cp;
            break;
        }
    }

    // get the remote host:port
    do {
        if (argc <= 0) {
            strcpy(url,"localhost:80");
            break;
        }
        strcpy(url,*argv++);
        --argc;
    } while (0);

    // get remote port number
    portstr = strchr(url,':');
    if (portstr != NULL)
        *portstr++ = 0;
    else
        portstr = "80";
    portno = atoi(portstr);

    // open the output file (or send to stdout)
    do {
        if (opt_o == NULL) {
            filefd = 1;
            break;
        }

        filefd = open(opt_o,O_WRONLY | O_CREAT,0644);
        if (filefd < 0)
            filefd = 1;
    } while (0);

    // establish connection
    sockfd = htpconn(url,portno);

    // send the file request
    htpget(sockfd,NULL,"/");

    // receive the server response
    htprcv(sockfd,filefd);

    close(sockfd);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that the OP really needs to parse the header for Content-Length.

Comment: @MartinJames Yes, I just realized that and was going to adjust my answer

Comment: I just tried your first solution, but the program fell into an endless loop. Σ（ ° △ °|||）︴the `ret` first time was `3343`, but next time and next next time the value become `0`, so the `remaining_size-=ret` will always greater than `0`, and endless loop.

Comment: Did you try the _second_ solution? That is what you need for `http` as I mentioned in my UPDATE section.

Comment: @CraigEstey Yeah, it hard to make the pseudo code run, and the returned values are all garbled. . .(⊙﹏⊙)